# remove columns either using command line or vim

Tags: shell, unix, vim, command-line

I have these text in file:

```
test1.out:www.xyx.com
test2.out:www.cnn.com
```

how could I remove first column before ':' and only left with:

```
www.xyx.com
www.cnn.com
```

Comment: Each capable text editor can use a regular expression for a global search and replace. If you need this on a regular base you can use `grep`, `sed` or `awk` in combination with regular expressions. Take a look at their `man` pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in vim using the `:g` command (see `:h :g`).

The command you should use is:

```
:g/.*/norm! df:
```

As FDinoff says in the comments, this simplifies to

```
:%norm! df:
```

This runs the commmand `norm! df:` on every line in the file. `norm! df:` will delete everything from the start of the line up to and including the `:`.

Comment: Which simplifies to `:%norm! df:`

Answer (score 1):

with awk

```
awk -F: '{print $2}' filename
```

with cut

```
cut -d: -f2 filename
```

with sed

```
 sed 's/.*://' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easily, by substituting everything before the `:` with nothing. From Vim:

```
:%s/^.*://
```

Comment: Be careful about greediness of `.*`. It will match to the last `:` on the line. This may not be what you want. You can over come this with `:%s/[^:]*:/` or `:%s/.\{-}://`.